# Panel is missing verticalscroll attribute

Tags: c#, scroll, panel

I'm trying to add a vertical scrollbar to a panel however the vertical scroll isn't working as the panel does not seem to have a vertical scroll attribute

```
ScrollBar vsbNotes = new VScrollBar();
vsbNotes.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
vsbNotes.Scroll += (sender, e) => { frmSupport.Controls["pNotes"].VerticalScroll.Value = vsbNotes.Value; };
vsbNotes.Visible = false;
vsbNotes.Name = "vsbNotes";
frmSupport.Controls["pNotes"].Controls.Add(vsbNotes);
```

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition
>   for 'VerticalScroll' and no extension method 'VerticalScroll'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: A panel will scroll when its content exceeds the client size available. Use the `AutoSize` property.  The bar will not be visible unless it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the AutoScroll property to true and dock all controls to the top of the panel or you will have to implement the behavior yourself. You could use the VScrollBar control for that.